# Dynamically creating oscillators causes memory issues in p5 Sound

Tags: javascript, audio, p5.js

Within my code (the code below is a very shortened version), I am creating oscillators (https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Oscillator) in draw. Eventually the audio starts crackling and being all weird, and I assume this is because the oscillators aren't being garbage collected? When looking at the Memory tab in Inspect Element, it continously goes up, and the audio goes crackly eventually.

I tried to dereference the oscillators using the two functions in my disconnect variable/function. This sets the oscillator to null after a specific amount of time I hope. I wasn't sure how to set a reference argument to null.

Maybe the p5 sound library still keeps references for them?

```
function createOsc(grid) {
  let osc = new p5.Oscillator();
  if (grids[grid].type == 1) {
    osc.setType("triangle");
  } else if (grids[grid].type == 2) {
    osc.setType("sawtooth");
  } else if (grids[grid].type == 3) {
    osc.setType("square");
  }
  return osc;
}

function createEnv(grid) {
  let env = new p5.Envelope();
  env.set(grids[grid].ADSR.attack, grids[grid].vol, grids[grid].ADSR.decay, grids[grid].ADSR.sustain * grids[grid].vol, grids[grid].ADSR.release, 0);
  return env;
}

let disconnect = {
  list: [],
  osc: function(osc, time) {
    this.list.push([osc, time, 0]);
  },
  update: function() {
    for (i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      this.list[i][2] += 1 / 60.0;

      if (this.list[i][2] >= this.list[i][1]) {
        this.list[i][0].a.disconnect();
        this.list[i][0].a = null;
        this.list.splice(i, 1);
        i += -1;
      }
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  let osc = createOsc(0);
  let env = createEnv(0);

  osc.start();
  osc.freq(420);
  env.triggerAttack(osc);
  env.triggerRelease(osc, env.aTime + env.dTime);
  osc.stop(env.aTime + env.dTime + env.rTime);
  disconnect.osc({a: osc}, env.aTime + env.dTime + env.rTime);
}
```

I attempted to use the PolySynth (https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.PolySynth) object, but I couldn't figure out how to change the waveforms or anything due to lack of clear documentation.

Edit:
This new standalone code produces the same crackling audio after a while. I am also now using Millis() as suggested. Same issue with memory constantly increasing.

```
let disconnect = {
  list: [],
  osc: function(osc, time) {
    this.list.push([osc, time, millis()]);
  },
  update: function() {
    for (i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      if (millis() - this.list[i][2] >= this.list[i][1]) {
        this.list[i][0].a.disconnect();
        this.list[i][0].a = null;
        this.list.splice(i, 1);
        i += -1;
      }
    }
  }
}

function createOsc() {
  let osc = new p5.Oscillator();
  osc.setType("triangle");
  return osc;
}

function createEnv() {
  let env = new p5.Envelope();
  env.set(0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0);
  return env;
}

function setup() {
  frameRate(60);
}

function draw() {
  disconnect.update();
  print(disconnect.list.length);
  
  if (frameCount % 2 == 0) {
    let osc = createOsc();
    let env = createEnv();
    
    osc.start();
    osc.freq(420);
    
    env.triggerAttack(osc);
    env.triggerRelease(osc, 0.2);
    
    osc.stop(0.3);
    
    disconnect.osc({a: osc}, 300);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Presumably you are calling update somewhere not shown, because if you don't then the `disconnect.list` is going to just grow infinitely. 2) The disconnect logic seems a little odd. Why assume that update will be called precisely 60 times a second? Why not calculate the time you expect the oscillator to have stopped and remove it when the real time (from `millis()` or `new Date()` or something) exceeds that time. 3) Creating a new Oscillator in every call to draw seems a bit odd unless you're significantly limiting frameRate...

Comment: ... If the envelop duration is longer than the interval between frames then you'll be accumulating more and more simultaneously running oscillators (and your `disconnect.list` array will continually grow).

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide a minimal working example that reproduces the issue and doesn't have broken/missing code (what's `grids`? where's your `setup` function? where/how are you calling `disconnect.update`?). There's a good chance that in the process of creating a minimal repro you identify whatever it is that you are doing that is causing the memory leak.

Comment: @A.Rad Out of curiosity, why do you need 30-60 oscilators per frame ? (would creating a few in setup and re-using them not suffice) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza My project lets the user place down notes and it plays it back to them, a music grid. I could reuse the oscillators by making a system that limits maximum voices and stuff, but I'm wanting to know if I am missing something obvious that can be fixed until I try that.

Comment: @PaulWheeler Thank you :) I created an edit with a minimal working example and implemented the millis() like you said. Sorry that I didn't do all this first time.

Comment: Hmm, when I run your code I don't see any obvious signs of a memory leak. I do hear the occasional crackle though. I would definitely try to refactor this so you don't have to create so many different oscillators in such quick succession.

Comment: @PaulWheeler Yeah, I did what I said and made a voices system by using oscillators. I think that fixes the issue, definitely less memory usage and stuff, I'll report back